# 2 connections to SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a problem, I want to have two connections:

- first database is on the server
- second database is local

How can I do it in ASP.NET? Can I use connection string?

Thanks

Comment: Two connection strings, two `SqlConnection` instances - absolutely no problem ...

Comment: can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to connect to two separate SQL Server instances at the same time, you need two connection strings in your `web.config` (or `app.config`), and you need to instantiate two `SqlConnection` objects.

Config:

```
<connectionStrings>    
    <add name="LocalConnection"
         connectionString="server=.;database=YourDb;Integrated Security=SSPI;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="RemoteConnection"
         connectionString="server=YourRemoteServerName;database=YourRemoteDbName;User ID=SomeUser;Password=Top$ecret" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And then in your code, you need to instantiate two `SqlConnection` objects:

```
// get the connection strings
string conStringLocal = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalConnection"].ConnectionString;
string conStringRemote = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RemoteConnection"].ConnectionString;

// create the two connections
SqlConnection conLocal = new SqlConnection(conStringLocal);
SqlConnection conRemote = new SqlConnection(conStringRemote);
```

Now, if you need to get something from the local database, use the `conLocal` connection for your `SqlCommand` etc. - and for your remote server, use `conRemote` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help.... its work on me... but if i put my asp in server so the client want access some data in his local database it same code?

Comment: @IanRelado: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.

Comment: if i instaled asp program in server but some private data get from client can i do that? if i use your solution its take local sql on server.. thanks